# Buscar a diff entre arrays diferentes

Tags: python, array, entrada-de-dados, diff

**OBJETIVO**

Eu tenho dois arrays onde contém informações formatadas diferentes, porém os dados são o mesmo, por exemplo no **ARRAY1** o **CLIENTE1-00** e o mesmo que o **CLIENTE1** do **ARRAY2**, eu preciso apenas fazer um `DIFF`para obter o que não pertencer entre o array 1 para o array2, que seriam as falhas, esses arrays são preenchidos com um `SELECT`, **ARRAY1** -> IBM DB2 e **ARRAY2** -> POSTGRES, uso as respectivas libs para isso `ibm_db_dbi` e `psycopg2`.

**PROBLEMA**

Estou enfrentando problemas com a forma que os dados estão dentro dos arrays, e na formatação do **ARRAY1** para o **ARRAY2**, não sei se o problema da formatação do **ARRAY1** está relacionado a API do BD, mas sempre que faço essa interseccão obtenho alguns erro relacionado aos ARRAYS.

**ARRAY 1**

```
(u'CLIENT1-00', u'SRVDADOS1:OS', u'MICROSOFT WINDOWS SERVER 2008 R2 STANDARD')
(u'CLIENT2-01', u'SRVDADOS2:OS', u'MICROSOFT WINDOWS SERVER 2008 STANDARD')
(u'CLIENT3-01', u'SRVDADOS3:OS', u'MICROSOFT WINDOWS SERVER 2008 STANDARD')
(u'CLIENT4-00', u'SRVDADOS4:OS', u'LINUX CENTOS')
(u'CLIENT5-00', u'SRVDADOS7:OS', u'MAINFRAME')
```

**ARRAY 2**

```
('CLIENT1', 'SRVDADOS1', 'Windows')
('CLIENT2', 'SRVDADOS2', 'Windows')
('CLIENT3', 'SRVDADOS3', 'Windows')
('CLIENT4', 'SRVDADOS4', 'Linux')
```

**OUTPUT DESAJADO**

```
["CLIENTE5","SRVDADOS7","MAINFRAME"]
```

**DETALHANDO A QUESTÃO**

A **COLUNA 1** DO ARRAY1 é o campo de nome do cliente, onde a única diferença entre o ARRAY 2 é que irá existir entre elas um hífen com uma numeração que varia de 00 para 01.

A **COLUNA 2** DO ARRAY 1 é o campo que contém o hostname do servidor, onde a única diferença entre o ARRAY 2 é o :OS (Consigo concatenar dentro select para adicionar o :OS)

A **COLUNA 3** DO ARRAY1 é o campo que contém o sistema operacional, que acredito que será o maior problema, pois o a diferença entre o ARRAY 2 é que vem junto a versão do sistema operacional, pensei em usar algo parecido com LIKE do SQL, para sempre que existe a palavra WINDOWS dentro do ARRAY 1 ele ignorar o resto e olhar apenas como WINDOWS, assim podendo comparar com o ARRAY 2

**Desenvolvido até o momento...**

[VISUALIZAR EM IDEONE.COM](https://ideone.com/ZnDDNR)

Comment: E qual é a saída esperada para esse exemplo?

Comment: Por exemplo, se existir um CLIENT5 no ARRAY1 com um HOST diferente do ARRAY2, deve ser retornado dentro de um novo array. newresult = ["CLIENTE5","SRVDADOS7","MAINFRAME"]

Comment: Então para o exemplo da pergunta a saída seria vazia? Os valores de host e do sistema operacional não serão levados em conta?

Comment: Seriam sim, o que eu preciso é moldar para que ambos os arrays fiquem idênticos para fazer essa comparação, e obter o que existe no ARRAY1 e não existe no ARRAY2

Comment: Os array vão ter cerca de 10mil registros, não sei até que ponto compensa usar IF...

Comment: No exemplo da pergunta, o cliente 1 possui `SRVDADOS1:OS` no array 1 e `SRVDADOS1` no array 2. Os valores são diferentes, então ele deveria estar na saída?

Comment: Os dados estão escritos de forma diferente, mas são o mesmo, isso é um erro que está dentro da base de dados do ARRAY1, ele não deveria vir por exemplo SRVDADOS:OS, e sim apenas SRVDADOS. O que eu preciso é transformar essas informações antes de fazer a comparação, porque se não sempre vai retornar como um DIFF, pq os dados estão escritos de forma diferente, mas representam a mesma coisa. O que seria o OUTPUT desejado, é o que realmente não existe entre eles...

Comment: É meio confuso essa questão...

Comment: Muito, então pedirei para que você edite a pergunta e descreva detalhadamente qual é o processo de transformação desses dados (de todos eles). Por exemplo, o nome parece que é só tratar até o hífen, mas isso é uma suposição. E se o nome possuir mais de um hífen? E se não possuir hífen? E se possuir letras minúsculas e maiúsculas? E se em um for `CLIENT1` e no outro `CLIENT01`? No host a mesma coisa... E no sistema operacional só piora a situação. Como irá extrair o nome simples do SO do primeiro *array* para comparar com o segundo?

Comment: Vou tentar explicar melhor na pergunta, mas o problema é complexo, por que estou preso a base de dados do ARRAY1, ela é minha referência, não tenho outro lugar para pegar como referência.

Comment: Em questão no Sistema Operacional eu pensei em usar algo parecido com LIKE do SQL, para quando ele identificar a palavra WINDOWS no começo dentro do ARRAY1, já modificar apenas para WINDOWS.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, reformulei, veja se facilita a compreensão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo, como seus arrays tem valores parcialmente diferente você vai precisar fazer as comparações manualmente, não vai ter um método pronto no python para lhe ajudar.
Se os dados que são iguais entre os 2 arrays fossem iguais você poderia fazer assim:

```
array1 = ['um', 'dois', 'três', 'quatro']
array2 = ['um', 'dois']
print(list(set(array1) - set(array2)))
```

A saída deste comando é:

```
['quatro', 'três']
```

Mas no seu caso, você vai ter que comparar se o elemento de um array contem o elemento do outro array, podendo ser feito desta maneira:

```
array1 = [(u'CLIENT1-00', u'SRVDADOS1:OS', u'MICROSOFT WINDOWS SERVER 2008 R2 STANDARD'),
(u'CLIENT2-01', u'SRVDADOS2:OS', u'MICROSOFT WINDOWS SERVER 2008 STANDARD'),
(u'CLIENT3-01', u'SRVDADOS3:OS', u'MICROSOFT WINDOWS SERVER 2008 STANDARD'),
(u'CLIENT4-00', u'SRVDADOS4:OS', u'LINUX CENTOS'),
(u'CLIENT6-00', u'SRVDADOS6:OS', u'LINUX CENTOS'),
(u'CLIENT7-00', u'SRVDADOS7:OS', u'LINUX CENTOS')]

array2 = [('CLIENT1', 'SRVDADOS1', 'Windows'),
('CLIENT2', 'SRVDADOS2', 'Windows'),
('CLIENT3', 'SRVDADOS3', 'Windows'),
('CLIENT4', 'SRVDADOS4', 'Linux'),
('CLIENT5', 'SRVDADOS5', 'Linux')]

new_result = []
#Procura o que tem no array2 e que não tem no array1
for row2 in array2:
  for row1 in array1:
    if row1[0].upper().__contains__(row2[0].upper()) and row1[1].upper().__contains__(row2[1].upper()) and row1[2].upper().__contains__(row2[2].upper()):
      #Se encontrou então passa pro próximo.
      break
    if row1[0] == array1[len(array1)-1][0] and not(row1[0].upper().__contains__(row2[0].upper()) and row1[1].upper().__contains__(row2[1].upper()) and row1[2].upper().__contains__(row2[2].upper())):
    #Se não encontrou adiciona o valor no new_result 
      new_result.append(row2)

#Procura o que tem no array1 e que não tem no array2
for row1 in array1:
  for row2 in array2:
    if row1[0].upper().__contains__(row2[0].upper()) and row1[1].upper().__contains__(row2[1].upper()) and row1[2].upper().__contains__(row2[2].upper()):
      #Se encontrou então passa pro próximo.
      break
    if row2[0] == array2[len(array2)-1][0] and not(row1[0].upper().__contains__(row2[0].upper()) and row1[1].upper().__contains__(row2[1].upper()) and row1[2].upper().__contains__(row2[2].upper())):
      #Se não encontrou adiciona o valor no new_result
      new_result.append(row1)

print(new_result);
```

Pode testar o código acima [aqui](https://repl.it/@MuriloPortugal/Python-testes)

Comment: Cara, se desse eu te dava duas verificação de resposta, ficou excelente, parabéns!!

Comment: Talvez seria interessante utilizar o operador `in` ao invés de chamar o método `__contains__` diretamente